# Why my rails project cannot show Bootstrap styles after changing all these files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My computer system is Mac OS. In the past few days, I was working on a rails project and I tried to use Bootstrap in my app. Followed by the instruction of Bootstrap website, I changed some files' contents but it still didn't work. Can somebody help me?
This is the code in application.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

This is the code in application.js:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
```

I have also run 'bundle install' on my console. However, nothing happened in my pages.

Comment: Have you followed this tutorial? -> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem

Answer (score 1):

Your `application.js` is missing the bootstrap files. Add those and you are good to go. Just add the below

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

to the `application.js`